# Setting up a subfolder's permissions differently to the parent folder for Samba

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, network-shares, samba

In Ubuntu 16, I've previously set up some shares each with different permissions. But that was always with the same permissions for the folder and its subfolders (done by using the "write list" and "read list" options).

Now I'm trying to set different permissions within an already existing share.

Let's say the share is `/.../share/`. Everybody has full permissions there.

But if you go down the tree to, let's say, `/.../share/subfolder1/`, I would like to change the permissions so that only the owner of that folder has full access and the other users cannot even see the contents of the folder.

But I cannot wrap my head around how to do that. If I make another share for `/.../share/subfolder1`, then I cannot access it directly (as it should be as I'm not the owner of it), but I can access it from its parent folder.

I don't have much experience setting up permissions on Linux-systems, and my attempts at googling a solution have failed.

Comment: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_Share_Using_Windows_ACLs ?

Comment: Thanks Alex! I didn't know this existed, although I followed a guide that created the smb.conf with ACL enabled. But since I didn't know what that did, I made my shares with "Force user" etc., overwriting the purpose of ACL etc.

I'm now editing the shares the way I want. I would mark your answer as an solution if I could.

Comment: Yeah, while Samba's wiki is indexed well by search engines, sometimes it tricky to create correct search terms to find original documentation instead of countless and misleading "How-to". I will post this link as an answer, so it may be would useful for someone too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While usually I do some excerpts from original links with my comments, I don't think it is a case when it applied to established product such as [samba](https://www.samba.org/). To avoid duplicating here official documentation, I will provide just a link to  [Setting_up_a_Share_Using_Windows_ACLs](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_Share_Using_Windows_ACLs) that describes settings one need for this particular question, so if in a future someone would need up to dated documentation regarding this subject one will be able to find it as well other useful information regarding Samba's settings at https://wiki.samba.org/ .